# propel model:build is not working in windows 8 when used propel 2.0

Tags: php, propel

I have installed Propel by following the instructions from [here](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html). To check that the propel is installed properly, I gave the command vendor\bin\propel a mentioned in the above link, but nothing happened. I tried the propel.bat file as well. I also downloaded the propel 2.0 as ZIP file and unzipped into the vendor folder. Still it did not work.

I have an existing database in mySQL. I have used the reverse engineering technique and generated the schema.xml. Now I am trying to build the model classes using propel and I have not luck. I have been searching in Google for last 4 hours, but no solution. Also I tried to run the propel.php from propel\bin folder in command prompt, it throws an error that "Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder' not found" though it is registered in autoloader. I learnt that classes from autoloader are not loaded when php is used through CLI.

Now I am wondering whether I should switch to Linux for PHP development.